# Centered Text Pushed Right in Flutter App Bar

Tags: flutter

I am looking for help in re-centering text in a Flutter App Bar that has been pushed right because of the back arrow on the left. Code snippet can be seen in the gist below:

https://gist.github.com/ezflutter/1258cc9522da1d06cdea7f7284a1e5a5

Comment: You should post your code inside triple back ticks instead of a link. You will get more willingness to help in my opinion. As for your question, I'm not experienced enough to be able to help but I'm sure someone else will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `centerTitle` property of AppBar instead as:

```
AppBar(
    backgroundColor: hdrcolor,
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Text(
       widget.myName,
       style: CustomTheme.bodyText1.override(
           fontFamily: 'Lexend Exa',
           color: txtcolor,
           fontSize: 26),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you, but that edit returned: Hot Reload Error DevFS synchronization failed

Comment: sorry, i had a typo, that works beautifully :)

Comment: If my solution fits your use case please accept is ;)